# Search does not work on "How To Ask" page

Tags: bug, search, asking-questions

On the [How To Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice) page the search box does not do anything. This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search box works for me in both browsers tested (Chrome and IE) on that page, but only if you type 3 or more keywords to search for.